# download Document object using spring mvc without jsp

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, itext, document

I am trying to create pdf file using POJO and download it using spring mvc.i have got the Document object but can not download the file. it gives error "could not find convertor".

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadPDF", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Document downloadPDF() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
    // create some sample data
    List<EmployeeInfo> employeeList = new ArrayList<EmployeeInfo>();
    employeeList.add(new EmployeeInfo("1", "Anish", "surat"));
     return downloadPDFService.createPDF(employeeList);
```

how can i download this file.
please provide answer

```
public Document createPDF( List<EmployeeInfo> employeeList) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

    Document document = new Document();
     PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("AddTableExample.pdf"));
        document.open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100); //Width 100%
        table.setSpacingBefore(10f); //Space before table
        table.setSpacingAfter(10f); //Space after table
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.BLUE);
        cell.setPadding(5);
        Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA);
        font.setColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
        cell.setPhrase(new Phrase("Id", font));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell.setPhrase(new Phrase("Name", font));
        table.addCell(cell);

        cell.setPhrase(new Phrase("Address", font));
        table.addCell(cell);
        for (EmployeeInfo aBook : employeeList) {
            table.addCell(aBook.getEmpId());
            table.addCell(aBook.getEmpName());
            table.addCell(aBook.getEmpAddress());
        }
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
        writer.close();
        return document;
}
```

this is a view creator.next is stack trace

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
No converter found for return value of     type: class com.itextpdf.text.Document
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.itextpdf.text.Document
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.itextpdf.text.Document
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:178)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:153)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:165)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: could you share the full stack trace???

Comment: Did you define any  PDF View ? Here is a complete example of [spring mvc pdf](http://www.kswaughs.com/2016/04/spring-mvc-pdf-view-example.html)

Comment: yes, i defined pdf view. i will share full code and stack trace

Comment: @kswaughs i don't want to use jsp, so i am not using ModelAndView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you don't want jsp, you still can use ModelAndView.

1. Change your DownloadPDFService as below.

   ```
   @Component
   public class DownloadPDFService extends AbstractPdfView {

   @Override
   protected void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Document doc,
       PdfWriter writer, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
       throws Exception {

       // Retrieve your model as below
       List<EmployeeInfo> employeeList =  (List<EmployeeInfo>) model.get("employeeList");

       // continue your document build logic

       }
     }
   ```
2. Change your controller as below

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadPDF", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public Document downloadPDF() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
      // create some sample data
      List<EmployeeInfo> employeeList = new ArrayList<EmployeeInfo>();
      employeeList.add(new EmployeeInfo("1", "Anish", "surat"));
      return new ModelAndView("pdfView", "employeeList",  employeeList);
   }
   ```
3. Add below views configuration in views.properties

   ```
   pdfView.(class)= YourpackageName.DownloadPDFService
   ```
4. Configure a new ResourceBundleViewResolver for above "views" properties.

Comment: Thank you @kswaughs It worked. Just change return type of downloadPDF Document to ModelAndView